# How to remove click blue line and hover of text field

Tags: reactjs

When I clicked into the text field it is showing blue outlined.
I want to hide this line. Also remove the mouse hovering.

```
<GridItem lg={ 6 } xs={ 12 } md={ 3 } className={ classes.textfieldsgrid } >
     <TextField 
       className={ classes.textfields } 
       label="Email" 
       variant="outlined" 
       id="outlined-size-small" 
       size="small" 
       style={ styles } 
       type="email" 
       name="email" 
       id="email" 
       value={this.state.email }
       onChange={ this.handleInputChange }
       onBlur={ event => this.validateEmail(event.target.value)}
       title="Email"
       autoComplete="off"
       required
      />
   <p class="error" style={ { color: 'red' } }>{ this.state.errors.email }</p>
</GridItem>
```

Comment: Just change the style of the TextField, take a look at the CSS API